# Расшифровка исходника онлайн трасляции

Tags: html, flash

Есть плеер от сайта Jampo. Ссылка на трянсляцию у него зашифрована и из-за этого внедрить этот плеер на сторонний сайт - невозможно. Нужно расшифровать код, чтобы получить прямую ссылку. Или же если это не возможно как прикрутить трянсляцию 2х2 к плееру?

Вот сама зашифрованная ссылка:

```
<param name="flashvars" value="netstreambasepath=http%3A%2F%2Ftv.jampo.com.ua%2Fplay%2Fchannel%2F2x2%2F&amp;id=myplayer&amp;file=2x2&amp;skin=%2Ffiles%2Fjwplayer%2Fblueratio.zip&amp;rtmp.session=eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxMzQ3MjE2OTkzLCAic2Vzc2lvbl9pZCI6IjBiMWYxN2E0OTZhMmQ5Yzc3N2Q3ZTBiZDA2NDI4OWU1M2MyYjlhYzUifQ%3D%3D--36dc9df875ed9335d143880543a28fcd7696daba&amp;rtmp.tunneling=false&amp;stretching=exactfit&amp;autostart=true&amp;streamer=rtmp%3A%2F%2F109.123.126.90%2Fstream%2F&amp;controlbar.position=over">eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxMzQ3MjE2OTkzLCAic2Vzc2lvbl9pZCI6IjBiMWYxN2E0OTZhMmQ5Yzc3N2Q3ZTBiZDA2NDI4OWU1M2MyYjlhYzUifQ
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (!window._iconAdd) window._iconAdd = (window.devicePixelRatio >= 2 ? '_2x' : '');
window.initPinBar = function(profile, mail, lng) {
  if ( !navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/msie (9|10)(\.?[0-9]*)*/) ) {
    return;
  }
  window.lang = extend(window.lang || {}, lng);

  var options = {
    applicationName: getLang('global_vkontakte'),
    startURL: '/feed',
    shortcutIcon: '/images/icons/' + (vk.intnat ? 'pinbar_favicon_vk' :'pinbar_faviconnew') + '.ico',
    taskIcon: '/images/' + (vk.intnat ? 'favicon_vk' :'faviconnew') + _iconAdd + '.ico',
    tasks: [
      { name: getLang('left_mynews'),  action: '/feed'},
      { name: getLang('left_mymessages'),  action: mail || '/im'},
      { name: getLang('left_myfriends'),  action: '/friends'},
      { name: getLang('left_mypage'),  action: profile || '/al_profile.php'}]
  };

  var lib = {
    meta: function(name, content) {
      return se('<meta name="'+name+'" content="'+content+'" />');
    },
```